# Find vector space $X$; so that vector space operations are not continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

How to choose $X$ to be a complex vector space with  a topology $\tau$ on $X$; so that vector space operations are not continuous  with respect to $\tau$; that is, the mappings, $X\times X \to X: (x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $\mathbb C \times X : (\alpha, x)\mapsto \alpha x$ are not continuous ?

Comment: Take $X = \mathbb{C}$ and choose a sufficiently bad bijection $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @ZL;thanks, which topology should I take ?

Comment: Try the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ for all $x\neq y$.

Comment: @Jochen If $X$ is discrete, then every function $X\times X\to X$ is continuous.

Comment: @egreg Sure, addition $X \times X\to X$ is then continuous but multiplication $\mathbb C \times X \to X$ fails to be continuous.

Comment: @Jochen The question asked for both maps not being continuous.

Comment: q egreg I noticed that. I didn't claim to answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concrete example, inspired by comments: define the metric 
$$
d(z,w) = \begin{cases}|z-w|, \quad &\text{ if } |z|,|w| \le 1 \text{ or }  z=w \\
|z-w| + 1 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
The triangle inequality is easy to check. The multiplication $z\mapsto 2z$ is not continuous because, e.g., $1-1/n \to 1$ but $2-2/n\not\to 2$. Similar for addition, like $z\mapsto z+1$.